# Abyssal Blood rage power functionality

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian

A few questions on the [Abyssal Blood](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/abyssal-blood-su) rage power:

- How long does it last? It does not state in the ability description. The most intuitive options are either that it lasts until you end your rage or that it lasts as long as the spell Enlarge Person, as that is referenced in the ability description.
- What is the caster level of the ability when it comes to things such as Dispel Magic and, if the duration is as Enlarge Person, duration? (Nevermind on the Dispel as it's SU rather than SP, I must have gotten confused at some point. I assume this means that the ability has no caster level.)
- More a question on Enlarge Person, but does the enlargement effect confer other effects related to size than just the ones stated in the spell description, such as increase in CMB and CMD or bonus on breaking items?

Comment: You should split at least the third question off separately. Questions should be separate, in general, unless there's a very good reason for them to be together. ("How do the unstated aspects of the rage power correspond to the spell?" is a fairly coherent single question, so I think your first two are acceptable together.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Duration

The increase in size lasts as long as the Barbarian is Raging. This is consistent with many other "Blood" *Rage Powers*. (*Celestial Blood*, *Draconic Blood*, etc.)

### Caster Level

It is not a spell nor a Spell-like ability and therefore it has no *Caster Level*. It is an ability that functions **in the same way** *Enlarge Person* functions but is not actually casting anything.

### Other Effects

Yes, increasing the size of a character brings with it all of the benefits and penalties associated with being a *Large* creature.